# Python: Why is this list comprehension 5000 times slower than the equivalent for loop?

Tags: python, performance, csv, list-comprehension

I have a Python script that reads 1000 lines from a CSV file.

Why is iterating the `csv.reader` object in a list comprehension 4 orders of magnitude slower than the equivalent explicit for loop?

Here are the code snippets and their times (via `time.time()`) on my machine:

```py
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = [r for i, r in enumerate(reader) if i < 1000]

# Time: 26.459498167037964 s
```

```py
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = []
    for i, r in enumerate(reader):
        if i >= 1000:
            break
        data.append(r)

# Time: 0.005597114562988281 s
```

EDIT:

As per the answers, the list comprehension version reads the whole file and only selects the elements that satisfy the condition `i < 1000`, while the explicit loop stops as it reaches `i == 1000`.

For future readers of this question, the most elegant solution was written by @decenze in the comments:

```py
import csv
from itertools import islice

with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = list(islice(reader, 0, 1000))
```

Comment: The list comprehension version doesn't `break`, so it's doing N iterations instead of 1000. Presumably the file you're using is really long (that's the N).

Comment: The list comprehension is reading all the lines in the file, even though it ignores all the ones after 1000.

Comment: You may be looking for `itertools.islice`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @Barmar was saying, your list comprehension is iterating over all your csv file lines and it is not stopping at index 1000, to stop at index 1000 you can use [islice](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = [r for r in islice(reader, 0, 1000)]
```

an equivalent code to your list comprehension to have a better understanding why is taking so long:

```
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = []
    for i, r in enumerate(reader):
        if i < 1000:
            data.append(r)
        # else iterate till the end of file
```

Comment: yep, but I was thinking  the OP wants some comparison btw for loop and list comprehension

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer

In this code,

```
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = []
    for i, r in enumerate(reader):
        if i >= 1000:
            break
        data.append(r)
```

in the `for` scope, the `for` scope will break if `i >= 1000`

But this in this code, there's no `break` keyword (since you used List Comprehension)

```
with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = [r for i, r in enumerate(reader) if i < 1000]
```

Why is this slow? Because `data = [r ...]` will not break if `i < 1000`, but will always read until `enumerate(reader)` is finished. This is different from the previous code where `for` scope will break if `i >= 1000`. But not for the list comprehension

You can use the similar code by using `raise StopIteration` or another method, for example

```
def LoopEnd():
    raise StopIteration()

with open("file.csv", 'r', newline = "\n") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ",")
    data = [r if i < 1000 else LoopEnd() for i, r in enumerate(reader)]
```

Comment: `else LoopEnd()` feels very very icky. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Well… it *works*, if that's what you mean. But so does `list(islice(reader, 1000))`, so I'm not sure why you'd ever consider this approach at all…

Comment: it's because using `islice` only work for integer, not for string

Comment: Say what now...?

Comment: for example, `[a if a == 'b' else LoopEnd() for a in "bbbcddd"]` will terminate before 'c' loop is executed

Comment: @deceze what did you mean?

Comment: `list(takewhile(lambda i: i == 'b', 'bbbcddd'))`…

Comment: oh, using `takewhile`. Well, perhaps it's more longer and complicated

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It is true that the `LoopEnd` version works with strings too, but it is more involved than the explicit loop, as it requires knowledge of the `StopIteration` exception that the `for` expects. 

For most cases, I think @deceze 's solution is the most elegant.

Comment: @Faran2007 Your `LoopEnd` does **not** work. Raising a `StopIteration` does **not** stop the iterations of the comprehensions it simply raises an exception rendering it impossible to obtain a result at all. So you should really use an other exception instead of `StopIteration` and also it works only when you don't care about the result but only the side-effects and if that's the case you shouldn't use a list-comprehension in the first place

Comment: Proof that it does not work: `>>> [i if i < 10 else LoopEnd() for i in range(100000)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in LoopEnd
StopIteration
>>> 
` note that no list was returned by the expression.

Comment: I suck at programming. Yes, you guys are right. I am sorry, my bad.